# Account balance function not returning a null row

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have the following setup where I am keeping track of different customers accounts and balances. For the most part everything is working fine.

In my setup I have 4 customers and when I call the function get_customer_balance(C.CUSTOMER_ID) I get back 4 rows, which I expect. Note  customer_id Y331964 has no TRANSACTIONS but I get a NULL back, which I want.

When I call the function get_account_balance  the account for Lisa comes back with a NULL, which I want but there is no row for Sandy. I can't, which is my problem. Can someone suggest how to fix my code to see that row?

Below is my test CASE. Thanks to all who respond.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
CUSTOMER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'E379466', 'Bonnie', 'Winterbottom','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'X060162', 'Lisa', 'Saladino','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Y331964', 'Sandy', 'Herring','Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Z888555', 'Barbara', 'Broadwater','Y' FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE customers 
ADD CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);

CREATE TABLE vendors AS
    SELECT level AS vendor_id,
       'Vendor ' || level AS vendor_name
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 3;

ALTER TABLE vendors 
    ADD ( CONSTRAINT vendors_pk
   PRIMARY KEY (vendor_id));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS (
ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
CUSTOMER_ID, VENDOR_ID,
IS_ACTIVE) AS 
SELECT 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D', 'Z888555', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU',
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B17ARWYYZRCU2Q2', 
'X060162', 3, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'E379466', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL  UNION ALL 
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW',
'E379466', 1, 'Y' FROM DUAL;


ALTER TABLE customer_accounts 
ADD CONSTRAINT customer_accounts_pk PRIMARY KEY (ACCOUNT_NUMBER);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT ca_customer_fk FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES customers(customer_id);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT ca_vendor_fk FOREIGN KEY (VENDOR_ID) REFERENCES vendors(vendor_id);

create table transactions (
     transaction_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    account_number VARCHAR2(15),
    transaction_type varchar2(1) DEFAULT 'C',
    transaction_amount NUMBER(10,2),
     transaction_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE 
);

ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ADD CONSTRAINT transactions_account_number_fk  FOREIGN KEY (ACCOUNT_NUMBER) REFERENCES customer_accounts
(account_number);

insert  into transactions(
account_number, transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date)
select '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'D', 555.25 * LEVEL, (DATE '2023-07-13' + 13/24) + (level * 2)  from dual 
    connect by level <= 25 
UNION ALL 
select '612ZKAQ66VA3W3', 'C', 555.25 * LEVEL, (DATE '2023-07-23' + 13/24) + (level * 2)  from dual 
    connect by level <= 20 
UNION ALL 
select 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D', 'D', 1125.25 * LEVEL, date '2023-01-23' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 11
union all
select 'BCHD9TW78W67S1D', 'C', 925.00 * LEVEL, date '2023-01-25' + level * interval '1 1' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 7
union all
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 'D', (LEVEL * 1250.50), date '2023-05-04' + level * interval '1 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 7
union all
SELECT '0HLS87LDR1TE8WB', 'C', (LEVEL * 1175.75), date '2023-05-04' + level * interval '1 15:13' day to minute from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU', 'D', ((LEVEL * 5) * 1750), date '2023-06-01' + level * interval '1 18:43:35' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 15
union all
SELECT 'Z69AG7DKS37UYU', 'C', ((LEVEL * 5) * 1750), date '2023-06-11' + level * interval '1 15:23:49' day to second from dual
          connect by level <= 13
union all
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW', 'D', (LEVEL * 100.57), date '2023-04-02' + level * interval '1 4' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT '0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW', 'C', (LEVEL * 25.26), date '2023-04-04' + level * interval '1 4' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 5
union all
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'D', (LEVEL * 250.10), date '2023-05-10' + level * interval '1 7' day to hour from dual
          connect by level <= 13
union all
SELECT 'THVQD6M9LR7AVK', 'C', (LEVEL * 133.11), (SYSDATE - LEVEL)  from dual
          connect by level <= 9;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION   get_customer_balance
(  i_customer_id   IN   customers.customer_id%TYPE
)
RETURN  transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE
IS
  v_balance   transactions.transaction_amount%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM (
                 CASE  t.transaction_type
             WHEN  'C'
             THEN  -t.transaction_amount
             ELSE  t.transaction_amount
         END 
             )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   customer_accounts  ca
  JOIN   transactions       t  ON  t.account_number  = ca.account_number
  WHERE  ca.customer_id  = i_customer_id  -- one customer
  OR     ca.customer_id  IS NULL;         -- all customers

  RETURN v_balance;
END  get_customer_balance;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_account_balance(
  i_account_number IN TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER%TYPE
) RETURN TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE
IS
  v_balance TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM(
           CASE transaction_type WHEN 'C' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
           * transaction_amount
         )
  INTO   v_balance
  FROM   transactions
  WHERE  account_number = i_account_number -- one account
  OR     i_account_number IS NULL;         -- all accounts
  RETURN v_balance;
END;
/

SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       C.IS_ACTIVE,
       get_customer_balance(C.CUSTOMER_ID) AS balance
FROM   customers c;



CUSTOMER_ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME IS_ACTIVE BALANCE
E379466 Bonnie Winterbottom Y 17898.8

X060162 Lisa Saladino Y
271127.75

Y331964 Sandy Herring Y -

Z888555 Barbara Broadwater Y
48366.5


SELECT CA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       CA.IS_ACTIVE,
       get_account_balance(ca.account_number) AS balance
FROM   CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS CA
       INNER JOIN customers c
       ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id;


ACCOUNT_NUMBER CUSTOMER_ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME 
IS_ACTIVE BALANCE

THVQD6M9LR7AVK E379466 Bonnie Winterbottom Y 16769.15

0Z76WT5NTLRZPTW E379466 Bonnie Winterbottom Y 1129.65

B17ARWYYZRCU2Q2 X060162 Lisa
Saladino Y -

0HLS87LDR1TE8WB X060162 Lisa
Saladino Y 17377.75

Z69AG7DKS37UYU X060162 Lisa
Saladino Y 253750

BCHD9TW78W67S1D Z888555 Barbara Broadwater Y 48366.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your final query to

```
SELECT CA.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
       C.CUSTOMER_ID,
       C.FIRST_NAME,
       C.LAST_NAME, 
       CA.IS_ACTIVE,
       get_account_balance(ca.account_number) AS balance
FROM   customers c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS CA
       ON ca.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

You know that CUSTOMERS has all of the customers, but each customer may or not be present in CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS. Thus, CUSTOMER should be your driving table and the join to CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS should be optional, or in other words it needs to be an outer join.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/DA2dowyW)